# Why child window is not appearing?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

```
HWND handleDesk = GetDesktopWindow();

BOOL visible=IsWindowVisible(handleDesk);



if(visible==true){WriteToLog("GetDesktopWindow:it is a visible window");}   

HWND handleChild=CreateWindowW(_T("STATIC"), L"abcd",
                              WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT |WS_CHILD|BS_MULTILINE, 80 ,270, 85,500,handleDesk,NULL,NULL,NULL);


BOOL visible1=IsWindowVisible(handleChild);
if(visible1==true){WriteToLog("handleChild :it is a visible window");}
```

I'm getting both the logs ("GetDesktopWindow:it is a visible window, handleChild :it is a visible window") in my log file which means that the child window is visible to me, but I'm not getting any child window in my screen. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't create windows that are children to the desktop

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You're also mixing window styles for two different classes; `BS_MULTILINE` can only be used on buttons, not on static controls.

Comment: You are calling [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956.aspx). Make sure you are intimately familiar with the consequences ([AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/19/10426841.aspx) or [I warned you: The dangers of attaching input queues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/01/8795860.aspx)).

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you have an odd mix of _T(""), L"" and plain "". If you are compiling for _UNICODE then you can simply call CreateWindow (instead of CreateWindowW), and your WriteToLog should take a `wchar_t *` pointer for consistency as well (not a plain `char *`). Otherwise _T("STATIC") should give at least a compiler warning which shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: @dxiv: `_UNICODE` controls the text mappings for the CRT. `UNICODE` controls the text mappings for the Windows API. See [TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/12/71851.aspx) for a full discussion.

Comment: @IInspectable You are correct, and that's a valid point when writing one's own makefiles. Within VC++ however both are conflated under the same `character setting` project setting.

Answer (score 1):

Creating child windows of windows that you don't own is fraught with peril.

You probably want an overlapped window rather than a child window.